# Stripe PHP - How do I retrieve the ID of the newly added card?

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to allow our customers to add multiple cards to their accounts. So at the checkout, they can select which card to use or add a new one.

I can select the already added card IDs by calling:

```
$cardid = $customer->sources->data[0]->id;
$cardid = $customer->sources->data[1]->id;
$cardid = $customer->sources->data[2]->id;
etc...
```

But I need to retrieve the card ID or the newly added card.

```
//Create Token
try {
$token = \Stripe\Token::create(
                array(
                        "card" => array(
                        "name" => $_POST['ccname'],
                        "number" => $_POST['ccnum'],
                        "exp_month" => $_POST['ccxpm'],
                        "exp_year" => $_POST['ccxpy'],
                        "cvc" => $_POST['cccvc'] )
)); }
catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
     $body = $e->getJsonBody();
     $err  = $body['error'];
    $status = $err['message'];
}       


// Add new Card to Custid
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($_POST['custid']);
$customer->sources->create(
                array(
                        "source" => $token['id']
));

$cardid = $customer->sources->data[]->id; ???

//  Charge CustID
$mysum = $_POST['amount']*100;

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
'customer' => $customer,
'amount'   => $mysum,
'currency' => 'usd',
'card' => $cardid
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [card creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card) will return the newly created [card object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object), so you can simply grab the ID from there:

```
$new_card = $customer->sources->create(array(
    "source" => $token['id']
));

$new_card_id = $new_card->id;
```

Note that Stripe will validate the card with the issuing bank when adding the new card to the customer, and may return a `card_error` if the validation fails. You should wrap the card creation request in a `try/catch` block to [handle possible errors](https://stripe.com/docs/api#error_handling).